# (Bidirectional) RNN for simple text classification

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

TL;DR: Is Bidirectional RNN helpful for simple text classification and is padding evil?

In my recent work, I created a LSTM model and a BLSTM model for the same task, that is, text classification. The LSTM model did a pretty good job, yet I decided to give BLSTM a shot to see whether it may even push the accuracy further. In the end, I found BLSTM much slower to converge and surprisingly, it overfitted, even though I applied dropout with the probability of 50%.

In the implementation, I used unrolled RNN for both LSTM and BLSTM, expecting for faster training. To meet the requirement, I manually padded the input texts to a fixed length.

Let's say we have a sentence "I slept late in the morning and missed th interview with Nebuchadnezzar", which is then padded with 0 at its end when converted to an array of indices of pre-trained word embeddings. So we get something like [21, 43, 25, 64, 43, 25, 6, 234, 23, 0, 0, 29, 0, 0, 0, ..., 0]. Note that the "th" (should be "the") is a typo and the name "Nebuchadnezzar" is too rare so both of them are not present in the vocabulary so we replace it with also 0, which corresponds to a special full-zero word vector.

Here are my reflections:

1. Some people prefer changing unknown words into a special word like "< unk >" before feeding the corpus into a GloVe or Word2Vec model. Does it mean that we have to first build the vocabulary and change some low-frequency words (according to min count setting) into "< unk >" before training? Is it better than changing unknown words into 0 or just removing them when training RNN?
2. The trailing 0s fed into LSTM or BLSTM networks, as far as I'm concerned, mess the output up. Although there is no new information from outside, the cell state still gets updated for each time step that follows, so the output of the final cell will be heavily impacted by the long trailing 0s. And to my belief, BLSTM will be impacted even more as it also processes the text from the inverse order, that is something like [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 321, 231], especially if we set the initial forget gate to 1.0 to foster memory at the beginning. I see a lot of people use padding but will not it cause a disaster if the texts are padded to a great length and in the case of BLSTM?

Any idea on these issues? :-o

Answer (score 2):

I agree mostly with Fabrice's answer above, but to add a few comments:

1. You should NEVER use the same token with UNK and PAD. Most deep learning libraries mask over PAD, since it provides no information. UNK, on the other hand, does provide information to your model (there is a word here, we just don't know what it is, and it's probably a special word), so you should not be masking that over. Yes, this does mean that in a separate preprocessing step, you should go through your training/testing data, build a vocabulary of, say, the top 10,000 most common words, and switch everything else to UNKs.
2. As noted in 1, most libraries simply mask over (i.e. ignore) padding characters, so this is not an issue. But as you said, it isn't necessary for you to pad the sentences. For example, you can group them by length while training, or feed in the sentences one at a time into your model.

Answer (score 1):

By experience, having a different embedding for `UNKNOWN` and `PADDING` is helpful.  Since you're doing text classification, I guess removing them wouldn't be too harmful if there aren't too many but I'm not familiar enough with text classification to say that with certainty.

As for padding your sequences, have you tried padding your sequences differently? For example, pad the beginning of your sequence for a forward LSTM and the end of a sequence for a backward LSTM. Since you're padding with zeros, the activations are not going to be as strong (if any) and your LSTMs will now end with your sequence instead of zeros which could overwrite your LSTM memory.

Of course, these are just suggestions out of the top of my head (I do not have enough reputation to comment) so I do not have THE answer. You'll have to try it out yourself and see if it helps or not. I hope it does.

Cheers.